# Node.js with mocha test

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js

if I have a function as the following:

```
function foo(request,response){
  var val = request.param('data');
  //code here
});
```

how can I create a mocha test function for this to pass the request and response parameters.

Answer (score 0):

The function you wrote above can be seen as a controller - it handles the request and gives back a response.

There are few things you can do:

1. You can test the route itself - make a http request to the endpoint which uses this controller and test if it behaves correctly - you can use `request/supertest/superagent` libraries for example.
2. You can mock the request and response objects and test the code directly - it doesn't require a server to be started, but you need to spend some time to mock out the objects correctly.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what your "code here" does, and what you want to do :

#### Test the logic

If you can separate the code in a method that accepts "val", and returns a result, then just test that. 
Usually, getting the params from a request, and passing the results to a response is a no-brainer, and not worth testing.

```
foo : function (req, res) {

  // Do you really need to test that ?
  var data = req.param("data");

  // You probably want to test that      
  var bar = doFooLogic(data);

  // Do you really need to test that ?
  res.json(bar);

},

doFooLogic : function (data) {
    ...
}
```

And a test like :

```
describe("foo's logic", function () {

  it("does stuff", function () {
     // Just test the logic.
     // This assumes you exposed the doFooLogic, which is probably acceptable
     var bar = doFooLogic(42);
     assert(bar.xxxx); // Whatever
  });

});
```

#### Test the req/response function:

If you really want that, if you're just using "param" on the request object, you might be able to easily mock the request / response (this is JS, you just need to pass something that has the same functions available) :

```
describe(..., function () {

  it("does whatever", function () {

    var mockRequest = {
      param : function (key) {
         if (key === "data") {
           return 42;
         } else {
           throw new Error("UNexpected key", key)
         }
      }
    }

    var mockResponse = {
      // mock whatever function you need here 
      json : function (whatever) {
           assert(whatever.xxxx) // compare what you put into the response, for example
      }
    }

    // Then do the call
    foo (mockRequest, mockResponse);

    // The hard part is then how to test the response was passed the right stuff.
    // That's why testing the logic is probably easier.
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can simply mock it with something like [Sinon.js](http://sinonjs.org/) . It should be something like this:

```
describe('...', function( done ){
 it('should test something', function(done){
   var mock = sinon.stub(request, "param").withArgs("data").returns("Whatever");

   var val = request.param('data');

   //do your logic with that value

   assert.equal(/*whatever value you want check*/);

   mock.restore();

   done();
 }
}
```

And you don't have to take care about request's content.